# Is it possible to flush and upload spark event logs without stopping SparkContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a long running Spark application with a single SparkContext that accepts multiple users via multiple SparkSessions. We would like to record Spark event logs in groups so that we don't have one massive Spark event log until the SparkContext is stopped so that we can more easily debug performance issues and analyze plans. So far the only way we've seen is to invoke `stop` on the SparkContext but were hoping for an explicit "flush" call we can make to the event listener to do periodic event logs without having to reinstantiate the SparkContext every time. Is this possible?

Comment: Rusty on my Log4J, but I think a rolling log file appender, specifying whatever max file size you like, might work.

Comment: Hmm that is one option but a little less deterministic than I was hoping for. That could potentially cut off some event logs belonging to a job group. Kind of hoping for something programatic so we can pause consuming more messages and flush.